# After inserting data into Cassandra with node.js, the program seems like it is still waiting

Tags: node.js, cassandra

I am really new to Cassandra and node.js now. I am trying to insert 200 data and it seems they are inserted into DB.

```
var client = new cassandra.Client({contactPoints: ['127.0.0.1'], keyspace: 'big'});
var insertRepo = 'INSERT INTO big.repo_info (id, name, full_name) '
    + 'VALUES(?, ?, ?);';

for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
    console.log(items[i].id, items[i].name, items[i].full_name);
    client.execute(insertRepo,
                   [items[i].id, items[i].name, items[i].full_name],
                   { prepare : true },
                   function (err) {
                     if (err) {
                       console.log(err);
                     } else {
                       console.log('done')
                     }
                   });
  };
```

However, after this transaction, it seems that the program is waiting for something without really done. So, I just press `ctrl-c` to exit the program. Is it normal or do I need to do something for this?

I think I missed something.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Node.js event loop will stay active until open connections are closed.

In this case, it means you need to call `client.shutdown()`.

Also, consider that `client.execute()` is an async operation, so invoking it from a sync loop it is generally not a good idea. You can use a workflow library instead, like the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) library.

```
async.timesSeries(items.length, function (n, next) {
  var params = [ items[i].id, items[i].name, items[i].full_name];
  client.execute(insertQuery, params, { prepare: true }, next);
}, function allFinished(err) {
  client.shutdown();
});
```

Check [async.timesSeries()](https://github.com/caolan/async#times) method for more information.

Comment: Additionally, I made callback function to use err from execute and put next into there because I found that some data caused errors and they made client pending. Thanks!